# Maven and Java version setting -- which solution is better?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have been searching for a solution to my Maven and Eclipse JRE version issue, where JRE 1.5 is being forced in the Eclipse project somehow even when I want different.

During my searches, I have noticed that there appear to be two different solutions to this. The first solution suggests using something like the snippet below

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <source>1.6</source>
           <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The second solution suggests using just two properties:

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Why are the two possible solutions and why do they differ?

Comment: Is your JavaCompiler in Eclipse project Java BuildPath set to 1.8?

Comment: @p1nkrock: It was just a copy/paste'd from a different source. I actually want to use 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a long way to specify it (by defining a `<plugin>` configuration in your pom file), which is the normal way to configure plugins, and there is a shorthand using a user property.

As you can find in the documentation.

> The -source argument for the Java compiler. Default value is: 1.5.
>
> User property is: maven.compiler.source.

If you only want to specify the source and target level, then there is no difference, but the `<plugin>` configuration also allows you to specify other configuration settings, restrict the versions of the compiler plugin, etc.

Comment: Adding to the comment. Every pom extends a base pom defined by maven resulting in an Effective-pom. the base pom has these properties, hence just setting these properties will be enough incase your goal is just set the correct compiler version. If any extra configuration to be made like to ignore test-compile etc, then you can use the first option where whole plugin is included in your pom.

Answer (score 1):

Many Maven plugins allow to use some properties to specify the parameters. The `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` properties are specified by the Maven Compiler Plugin.

See the "User Property" sections:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#target

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html